# Showing all components in inventory with total stock

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table which shows displays list of all works orders with part numbers and quantities booked in those works orders as stock awaiting polishing.

What I want, is to list all part numbers in order to display total number of stock per part.

The current output is:

```
=======================================================
**Works Order** | **Part Number** | Stock Awaiting Polishing + other columns
1               | B01             | 5       
2               | B012            | 12     
3               | B012            | 43         
4               | B014            | 32
```

What I want to Display is:

```
=======================================================
**Part Number** | Stock Awaiting Polishing
B01             |            5       
B012            |            55     
BO14            |            32
```

This may be easy but I'm still learning, can I get some help here?

```
SELECT
  data.WORKS_ORDER1 AS Works_Order,
  data.PART_NO1 AS Part_Number,
  data.Part_Prim_Desc AS Part_Description,
  data.Part_Secd_Desc AS Customer,
  data.Qty_Painted,
  data.Qty_Processed,    
  data.Available_Stock AS Stock_Awaiting_Polishing
FROM (
  SELECT
    wip.WO.WO_No AS [WORKS_ORDER1],
    wip.WO.Part_No AS [PART_NO1],
    wip.Ops.WO_No AS [WORKS_ORDER2], 
    production.Part.Part_No AS [PART_NO2],    
    production.Part.Part_Prim_Desc,
    production.Part.Part_Secd_Desc, 
    wip.WO.Qty_Inc_Scrap AS Qty_Painted, 
    wip.Ops.Qty_Complete + wip.Ops.Qty_Rejected 
      + wip.Ops.Qty_Scrapped AS Qty_Processed,
    wip.WO.Qty_Inc_Scrap - (wip.Ops.Qty_Complete 
      + wip.Ops.Qty_Rejected + wip.Ops.Qty_Scrapped) AS [Available_Stock]
  FROM wip.Ops
    INNER JOIN wip.WO ON wip.Ops.WO_No = wip.WO.WO_No
    INNER JOIN production.Part ON wip.WO.Part_No = production.Part.Part_No  
  WHERE wip.WO.WO_Complete = 0 AND wip.WO.No_of_Ops_Completed = 1 
    AND wip.Ops.Op_No = 20 AND wip.Ops.WC_Code = 'VPO' AND wip.Ops.Completion_Ind_YN = 'N'
  GROUP BY wip.WO.WO_No,   wip.WO.Part_No,
   wip.Ops.WO_No,
   production.Part.Part_No,
   production.Part.Part_Prim_Desc,
   production.Part.Part_Secd_Desc,
   wip.WO.Qty_Inc_Scrap,
   wip.Ops.Qty_Complete, 
   wip.Ops.Qty_Rejected,    
   wip.Ops.Qty_Scrapped
) data    
WHERE data.Available_Stock > 0
```

I'm starting my journey with SQL and the above code most likely could be simplified a lot, but it's all I've got and it works the way I want.

All help appreciated!

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: I'm using MySQL, thanks

Comment: What of works_order, customer, quantity_paited and qty_processed, what should happen to them, they need for evey column a https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: What I want to display is the part number, part description, customer and total available stock, nothing else. Total stock is made of quantity processed minus quantity painted.

Comment: What's the point of `GROUP BY` without aggregation?

Comment: Ok i try to explain you want costomer for example, is there only one costumer or more of them and if there are more, which to choose. This you have to decide for every row you want to show. except Part Number** | Stock Awaiting Polishing, part_desciption should always be the same for each part_number so a min should suffice

Comment: This is exactly why I’m here guys